# 'expo-cli' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. This command requires Expo CLI

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo, npm-install

```
 **npm install --global expo-cli**  
    npm WARN deprecated subscriptions-transport-ws@0.9.8: The `subscriptions-transport-ws` package is no longer maintained. We recommend you use `graphql-ws` instead. For help migrating Apollo software to `graphql-ws`, see https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/#switching-from-subscriptions-transport-ws    For general help using `graphql-ws`, see https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/blob/master/README.md
    npm WARN deprecated graphql-tools@3.0.0: This package has been deprecated and now it only exports makeExecutableSchema.\nAnd it will no longer receive updates.\nWe recommend you to migrate to scoped packages such as @graphql-tools/schema, @graphql-tools/utils and etc.\nCheck out https://www.graphql-tools.com to learn what package you should use instead
    npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
    npm WARN deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.
    npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
    npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x 
    fewer dependencies
    npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
    npm WARN rollback Rolling back resolve-from@3.0.0 failed (this is probably harmless): EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 
    'C:\Users\Korisnik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\import-fresh\node_modules'
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@~2.3.2 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} 
    (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.7 (node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} 
    (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
    
    npm ERR! code EPERM
    npm ERR! syscall unlink
    npm ERR! path C:\Users\Korisnik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\AdbWinUsbApi.dll
    npm ERR! errno -4048
    npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Korisnik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\AdbWinUsbApi.dll'
    npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Korisnik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\AdbWinUsbApi.dll'] {
    npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Korisnik\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\.xdl.DELETE\binaries\windows\adb\AdbWinUsbApi.dll'] {
    npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
    npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
    npm ERR!     syscall: 'unlink',
    npm ERR!     path: 'C:\\Users\\Korisnik\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\expo-cli\\node_modules\\.xdl.DELETE\\binaries\\windows\\adb\\AdbWinUsbApi.dll'
    npm ERR!   },
    npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
    npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
    npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
    npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\Korisnik\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\expo-cli\\node_modules\\.xdl.DELETE\\binaries\\windows\\adb\\AdbWinUsbApi.dll',
    npm ERR!   parent: 'expo-cli'
    npm ERR! }
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
    npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
    npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
    npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
    npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

'expo-cli' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. This command requires Expo CLI. I am trying to install expo and nothing is working. My enviroment variables PATH:
Path

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Korisnik\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\Korisnik\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\Korisnik\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by restarting computer.